# Live (e)grepping on a file

Tags: grep

Every week or so I need to load a file that has millions of lines and start running greps on it. Some greps are positive, some are negative ("-v" flag). Some are grep and some are egrep.

I do it manually today - run a grep, save the results to a file, then run another grep on this file and save to file2, then file3, etc.

Is there some tool that can make my life easier where I can easily manipulate a list of greps, egreps, that the tool will calculate and show the results live? The tool needs to cache the results of previous greps to avoid re-running them all each time.

Comment: Um … put the commands that you currently run manually into a script?

Comment: No, it's highly dynamic. I need to be able to add greps, turn some on/off, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "show the results live" (but see the end of my answer for an idea) but generally I'd use **make** for this sort of task. For example, given a file *srcfile.txt* on which I'm going to run a number of greps, I'd put the greps in a makefile something like this:

```
all: e.out b.out zy.out

single: e.out b.out

e.out: srcfile.txt
    grep e srcfile.txt >e.out

b.out: srcfile.txt
    grep b srcfile.txt >b.out

zy.out: srcfile.txt
    grep zy srcfile.txt >zy.out
```

... I can then run all the greps that are required to bring the output files up-to-date with

```
> make
```

... I can run all the greps that search for single letters with

```
> make single
```

... etc. Over a few weeks in your situation, I think I'd quickly accumulate a set of *make* rules that covered all (or almost all) of the cases in which I was interested.

You might be able to save some more time and effort by putting the commands to load your million+ line file in the makefile as well.

If choosing one or more targets using the *make* command doesn't provide enough flexibility, you could use conditionals in the make file, based on variables that you set when running *make*, e.g. see the [GNU makefile tutorial on conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals) and [this article on passing variables from the *make* command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make).

To show the results of the grepping as it happens, I would be inclined to use *tail* or *less* as recommended [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1669/shell-command-to-monitor-changes-in-a-file-whats-it-called-again). A difficulty is that either method only shows one file at a time. I'd need to know more about your need for "live" viewing to know if that might be satisfactory or if another solution might be required.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: In that case, could you expand a bit on just what you're looking for? Thanks.

Comment: Something that allows me to select a single file, add egreps as separate patterns, turn some on and off and see how it changes the result. It needs to be easy to use, not a script that I edit again and again.